# How to debug PodMonitor generated rules?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have this repo [terraform1#prometheus-operator](https://github.com/kokizzu/terraform1/pull/1), got it working previously with normal prometheus (without operator), now testing for prometheus-operator so if pod scaled horizontally, it would still can scrape correctly all metrics for all pods, not just from 1 pod.

This [article](//kokizzu.blogspot.com/2023/07/keda-kubernetes-event-driven-autoscaling.html) step by step how to run the minikube and terraform.

After deployed, it shows properly:

```
k get pods -n pf1ns -w                                                                    1 ↵
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
keda-admission-webhooks-76cd6c4b59-6b59r           1/1     Running   0          20h
keda-operator-5bb494667b-bb2bl                     1/1     Running   0          20h
keda-operator-metrics-apiserver-68d9f78869-d65vj   1/1     Running   0          20h
prometheus-pf1prom-0                               2/2     Running   0          3m9s
promfiberdeploy-868697d555-2jfgv                   1/1     Running   0          20h
```

no error on `prometheus-pf1prom-0`:

```
ts=2023-07-04T17:37:42.315Z caller=main.go:1257 level=info msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml totalDuration=554.419µs db_storage=1.312µs remote_storage=1.232µs web_handler=410ns query_engine=851ns scrape=36.078µs scrape_sd=187.441µs notify=681ns notify_sd=1.453µs rules=922ns tracing=2.856µs
```

What's the config missing from the rules generated by PodMonitor?

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 30s
  external_labels:
    prometheus: pf1ns/pf1prom
    prometheus_replica: prometheus-pf1prom-0
scrape_configs:
- job_name: podMonitor/pf1ns/pf1prompodmonitor/0
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  enable_http2: true
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [job]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: __tmp_prometheus_job_name
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_phase]
    separator: ;
    regex: (Failed|Succeeded)
    replacement: $1
    action: drop
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app, __meta_kubernetes_pod_labelpresent_app]
    separator: ;
    regex: (promfiber);true
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: "3000"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: namespace
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: container
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: job
    replacement: pf1ns/pf1prompodmonitor
    action: replace
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: endpoint
    replacement: "3000"
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    modulus: 1
    target_label: __tmp_hash
    replacement: $1
    action: hashmod
  - source_labels: [__tmp_hash]
    separator: ;
    regex: "0"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
    kubeconfig_file: ""
    follow_redirects: true
    enable_http2: true
    namespaces:
      own_namespace: false
      names:
      - pf1ns
```

the rules:

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "pf1prompodmonitor" {
  manifest = {
    "apiVersion" = "monitoring.coreos.com/v1"
    "kind"       = "PodMonitor"
    "metadata"   = {
      "name"      = "pf1prompodmonitor"
      "namespace" = var.nsname
      "labels"    = {
        "name" = "pf1podmonitor"
      }
    }
    "spec" = {
      "selector" = {
        "matchLabels" = {
          "app" = kubernetes_deployment_v1.promfiberdeploy.spec.0.selector.0.match_labels.app # -> promfiber
        }
      }
      "namespaceSelector" = {
        "matchNames" = [
          var.nsname
        ]
      }
      "podMetricsEndpoints" = [
        {
          "interval" = "5s"
          "port"     = kubernetes_deployment_v1.promfiberdeploy.spec.0.template.0.spec.0.container.0.port.0.container_port # -> 3000
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

the pod deployment that need to be scraped:

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment_v1" "promfiberdeploy" {
  metadata {
    name      = "promfiberdeploy"
    namespace = var.nsname
  }
  spec {
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "promfiber"
      }
    }
    replicas = "1"
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "promfiber"
        }
        annotations = {
          "prometheus.io/path"   = "/metrics"
          "prometheus.io/scrape" = "true"
          "prometheus.io/port"   = 3000
        }
      }
      spec {
        container {
          name  = "pf1"
          image = "kokizzu/pf1:v0001" # from promfiber.go
          port {
            container_port = 3000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

there's no error at all at prometheus, but it also doesn't scrape anything, the targets on GUI is empty.

Service discovery is there, but all have status "dropped"

[image: service discovery]

there is one that match "promfiber", but also the status is dropped

[image: promfiber dropped]

```
__address__="10.244.0.45:3000"
__meta_kubernetes_namespace="pf1ns"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path="/metrics"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port="3000"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape="true"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotationpresent_prometheus_io_path="true"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotationpresent_prometheus_io_port="true"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotationpresent_prometheus_io_scrape="true"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_id="docker://abbc5c17e873b730fdc6e490917b72ccb4ec8a45f4a250d6fb5f8be4ce95b59b"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_image="kokizzu/pf1:v0001"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_init="false"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name="pf1"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number="3000"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_protocol="TCP"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_controller_kind="ReplicaSet"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_controller_name="promfiberdeploy-868697d555"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_host_ip="240.1.0.2"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_ip="10.244.0.45"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app="promfiber"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_pod_template_hash="868697d555"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_labelpresent_app="true"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_labelpresent_pod_template_hash="true"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_name="promfiberdeploy-868697d555-2jfgv"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name="minikube"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_phase="Running"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_ready="true"
__meta_kubernetes_pod_uid="ad529d61-67f0-4867-b2a6-5c9915870b20"
__metrics_path__="/metrics"
__scheme__="http"
__scrape_interval__="5s"
__scrape_timeout__="5s"
job="podMonitor/pf1ns/pf1prompodmonitor/0"
```

Comment: Is this about programming?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently caused by `"port" = 3000`

```
"podMetricsEndpoints" = [
   {
     "interval" = "5s"
     #"port"     = kubernetes_deployment_v1.promfiberdeploy.spec.0.template.0.spec.0.container.0.port.0.container_port
   }
]
```

adding that line causes a filter to be applied `__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name` regex should match string `"3000"`.

removing that line causing nothing being dropped.

Also another gotcha, you cannot match with label containing dot `.` or slash `/` it would never match.